# Apache Beam Java ElasticsearchIO error for AWS OpenSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to deploy an Apache Beam batch processing pipeline in a GCP project. My pipeline will read from an Elasticsearch cluster in AWS OpenSearch.

Here's my code that I've written for doing the same:

```
        ElasticSearchOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation()
                .as(ElasticSearchOptions.class);

        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

        options.setAwsCredentialsProvider(
                new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(
                        options.getAwsAccessKey(),
                        options.getAwsSecretKey()
                )
            )
        );
        options.setAwsRegion("us-east-1");

        PCollection<String> output =
            pipeline.apply(
                    ElasticsearchIO.read().withConnectionConfiguration(
                            ElasticsearchIO.ConnectionConfiguration.create(
                                    <hostName>,
                                    options.getElasticSearchIndex(),
                                    options.getElasticSearchType()
                                    )
                    )
                .withQuery("field_name:some-value")
            );
```

I'm getting an error

```
403: User anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHTTPGet
```

To understand this error better, I printed the AWS secret and access key from my worker node to ensure that the values passed were getting processed properly. And it is!

I'm stuck at this point. How do I authorize myself with my AWS credentials (access and secret key) and sign my requests for the Elasticsearch Read operator?

Answer (score 0):

I may guess that `ElasticsearchIO` knows nothing about AWS credentials and `AwsCredentialsProvider` that you set before and it uses only an instance of `ConnectionConfiguration`, which you pass to `.withConnectionConfiguration()`, to connect to cluster.

So, you may try to set your username/password by `ConnectionConfiguration withUsername(String)` and `ConnectionConfiguration withPassword(String)` if they are the same as AWS credentials (tbh, I don't know how Elasticsearch authentication works with AWS OpenSearch).

Comment: Thanks for the response. That makes sense! I'll try using the username/password authentication method. 
As a side-note, I also updated the access policy in the ES cluster and whitelisted the Dataflow worker IPs.